# how to grab the name and picture of a discord server in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, webhooks

Hi i am wondering how you would grab the server name of a discord invite. Example `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/H4ySkbn` with `H4ySkbn` being the server invite code

It will bring you to a page like this [image: page after opening link]

This part being the bit I need to grab

[image]

The reason I need the name and server profile picture is to embed it in this webhook

[image: webhook]

If anyone knows a way to do this using the discord API or a different way, an answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want this in discord.js or using the API no wrapper? Tags include both and post includes both

Comment: @karizma Hi I don't really mind, I'm just I need of a working way to grab the server name and picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use discord.js you can simply use `<Client>.fetchInvite()`:

```js
const client = <Client>
client.fetchInvite(invite_url)
      .then(console.log);
```

Which would return an Invite instance:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite

after that just access the guild by `.guild`:

```js
const client = <Client>
client.fetchInvite(invite_url)
  .then(inv => {
    console.log(inv.guild);
    console.log(inv.guild.name, inv.guild.iconURL());
  });
```

If you want to use `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/H4ySkbn` just fetch the link with axios or node-fetch resolve it in JSON and then access the properties there, but in that case the icon url will be a hash